# MSYS2: How to disable automatic translation of pathname to drive letter?

Tags: c, shell, mingw, msys, msys2

I'm facing an issue when testing a C program compiled with mingw in the MSYS2 shell: I wrote a command line parser that accepts options according to the windows convention (starting with `/`). If I call my program like this to generate an output file:

```
./example.exe /o test
```

What ends up in `argv[1]` is actually `O:/`. It works fine when testing from a console window running `CMD.EXE`. This truly minimal program demonstrates the behavior:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        puts(argv[1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
$ ./example.exe /o
O:/
```

So I guess this is the MSYS2 shell trying to be helpful and replacing something that looks like a one-letter path below root into a drive-letter syntax. Is there a way to disable this behavior? It's a bit of a hassle to always launch `CMD.EXE` for testing.

Comment: Not related to C. Did you try escaping or enclosing in ticks/`"`?

Comment: @Olaf MSYS2 is a development environment *for* C and the rule of thumb is *one* language tag is nearly always appropriate! Same thing as questions about the command line arguments of `clang` or a `Makefile` for building some C code... and of course I tried *obvious* things like that!

Comment: @Olaf and the vote to migrate is wrong as well, see [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), especially "*software tools commonly used by programmers*"

Comment: The shell in question is part of [MSYS2](http://www.msys2.org/), citing from there: "*MSYS2 is a software distro and building platform for Windows*" -- definitely a "*tool commonly used by programmers*". Also, stop your destructive edits here, see for example [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298019/is-it-ok-to-use-language-specific-tags-for-problems-with-that-are-not-directly-c)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL` environment variable to disable this behavior.  For example, try running:

```
MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL=\* ./example.exe /o test
```

Comment: Great, solves the issue, thanks. Do you have a resource explaining the content of this environment variable?

Comment: I can't find it at the moment, but it's basically a list of argument prefixes separated by some separator character.

Comment: Okay, I'll search for it myself and meanwhile just remember the name :)

Comment: Is there a similar function for ConEmu / Mingw64 ?

Comment: The important thing is what shell you are using (e.g. bash.exe), not the terminal emulator.  If it's an executable that uses the MSYS2 runtime (msys-2.0.dll), MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL should work.

Comment: The documentation is at https://www.msys2.org/docs/filesystem-paths/#automatic-unix-windows-path-conversion.