# Makefile command line arguments confused with MinGW directory paths

Tags: command-line, mingw, msys

I'm trying to run a `make all` command but I get a very confusing error, it seems as if the arguments from 'cl' are mistaken as directory paths in MinGW. The output I'm getting:

```
cl /EHsc /MD /nologo /D_SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS -nologo /O2 -DN
DEBUG -DUSE_CBC -DUSE_CLP /D__WIN32__ /Iinclude\\src\\windows /DGFLAGS_DLL_DECL=
 /DGFLAGS_DLL_DECLARE_FLAG= /DGFLAGS_DLL_DEFINE_FLAG= /Iinclude /I. -DUSE_GLOP -
DUSE_BOP -c examples\\cpp\\costas_array.cc /Foobjs\\costas_array.obj
```

That's the cl command, not the warnings and errors (note that `cl /EHsc` actually gets mistaken for `'C:/MinGW/MSYS/1.0/EHsc'`, etc...):

```
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'C:/MinGW/MSYS/1
.0/EHsc', object file assumed
cl : Command line warning D9027 : source file 'C:/MinGW/MSYS/1.0/EHsc' ignored
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'C:/MinGW/MSYS/1
.0/MD', object file assumed
cl : Command line warning D9027 : source file 'C:/MinGW/MSYS/1.0/MD' ignored
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'C:/MinGW/MSYS/1
.0/nologo', object file assumed
cl : Command line warning D9027 : source file 'C:/MinGW/MSYS/1.0/nologo' ignored
```

... etc ... Until there's the `fatal error` at the end

```
cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'C:/MinGW/MSYS/1
.0/I.', object file assumed
cl : Command line warning D9027 : source file 'C:/MinGW/MSYS/1.0/I.' ignored
cl : Command line warning D9027 : source file 'C:/MinGW/MSYS/1.0/Foobjs/costas_a
rray.obj' ignored
costas_array.cc
examples\cpp\costas_array.cc(27): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: '
ortools/base/callback.h': No such file or directory
make: *** [objs\\costas_array.obj] Error 2
```

Any help about why is this happening would be highly appreciated, I am not very experienced in this matter.

Answer (score 2):

It's the MSYS shell doing these translations for you in an attempt of being helpful.

With the tools typically used in this shell, it's no problem because arguments/options start with a `-` or `--` (the Unix and/or GNU convention). It starts getting into your way as soon as you need command-line tools following the Microsoft convention for options and flags, using `/`.

Unfortunately, for the original MSYS, I'm not aware of a way to disable this translation. But there is one for MSYS2, [see the question I asked about it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44700461/2371524): You just need to set an environment variable, e.g.

```
export MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL=\*
```

So, my suggestion would be you upgrade your tools to [MSYS2](http://www.msys2.org/) and use this.