# Curl changes multipart/form-data path parameter

Tags: shell, curl, msys, synology

I try to send some multipart/form-data data using curl in a msys shell to a NAS named Synology. The form-data needs a parameter named "path" and must formated like "/dir/dir2". The slashes can't be changed.
My problem is, when i am using curl the path variable will be changed to "C:/git-sdk-64/dir/dir2" and i don't know how to prevent it. My command looks like this:

```
curl -X POST \
  'http://url:port/webapi/entry.cgi?_sid=secret&api=SYNO.FileStation.Upload&method=upload&version=2' \
  -F "path=/dir/dir2" \
  -F 'overwrite=true' \
  -F 'filename=@/c/Temp/test.txt'
```

Comment: curl doesn't change the path, something else does it. Are you perhaps using msys? It is known to do those things when trying to be "helpful".

Comment: Ok. Thats some good info i can start with.I am new to this bash and shell world. And i must use msys. Nothing else i can use.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44700461/msys2-how-to-disable-automatic-translation-of-pathname-to-drive-letter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Daniel Stenberg's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/93747/daniel-stenberg) info i found out this is a "problem" with msys self. Msys fills up the path variable. Written down here http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion. The solution is to put an semicolon at the end of the path. The complete command now looks like this:

```
curl -X POST \
  'http://url:port/webapi/entry.cgi?_sid=secret&api=SYNO.FileStation.Upload&method=upload&version=2' \
  -F "path=/dir/dir2;" \
  -F 'overwrite=true' \
  -F 'filename=@/c/Temp/test.txt'
```